# Put g_timeout_add () on hold without being removed

Tags: glib

I try to put **g_timeout_add ()** on hold in if it meets one condition without being removed with **g_source_remove ()**.

Basically pause/resume thread.

From documentation [g_timeout_add ()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-seconds) I do not realize how this could be achieved

Now can do this with:

```
    void
    schedule_popup (gpointer data)
    {
            unschedule_popup (data);
            timeout_id = g_timeout_add_seconds (POPUP_TIMEOUT, (GSourceFunc) hide_popup_timeout_cb, data);
            g_source_set_name_by_id (timeout_id, "[myapp] hide_popup_timeout_cb");
    }

    void
    unschedule_popup (gpointer data)
    {
            if (timeout_id > 0)
                    g_source_remove (timeout_id);
            timeout_id = 0;
    }
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, both idles and timeouts executes within main thread, so if you lock it you're locking main thread, which isn't a good idea. Depending on your needs, it is probably better to spawn separate thread and wake it with semaphore.

Comment: What's wrong with the way you're doing it?